# Verbless, list-like sentence

Tags: copywriting

In copywriting, I got to wonder if the combination of a verbless sentence followed by exclamation is anywhere near correct grammatically.  Here's how it is at the moment: 
"Compliance, gaps, contacts, friction? That’s OK."

Nevermind the technical meaning.  It could have just been

"Coffee, tea, wine, gravy?   All those stains will vanish.

Verbless sentences are rare and my search engine finds nothing near this kind of usage.

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this as a copywriting question. Additionally, the title is vague and not a question. However, what I understand is that you're asking about grammatical correctness which would make this question off -topic here. You may post on [https://english.stackexchange.com].

Comment: This is a grammatical question, more suited to [english.se].

Comment: Depends, **who is your audience**? If it's pedantic grammarians, they would spit on the page/screen. If it's a sales pitch, it would fine. You're trying to sell a product/get an idea across, not show your mastery of English grammar.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your grammar question, *but* - it's super common for people to say things that aren't grammatically correct. Nobody analyzes it. If it's casual dialogue, this is certainly true. As long as it's understandable, it's okay to use sentence fragments, verbless phrases, etc. because that's how people talk in real life

Comment: The main question is whether this is a known,  effective way to communicate.  That's why I specified the copywriting context. 

Apologies for posting in the wrong thread.  I landed here when searching for "verbless sentences".    

I can of course delete the post.